# Transactions across permanent and ephemeral (in-memory) data

Tags: c++, sql, transactions

I'd like to have transactions that span across both persistent data and in-memory data. Basically, I'd like to do something like this (in pseudocode form):

```
 1: try
 2:     begin transaction;
 3:     query the database;
 4:     update memory;
 5:     update the database;
 6:     commit transaction;
 7: catch (exception E)
 8:     rollback transaction;
 9:     throw E;
10: end try
```

Where, when we roll back the transaction in line 8, the updates in line 4 are *also* rolled back. I understand that a general solution to rolling back the line 4 updates may be impractical. However, are there techniques, data structures, or libraries that will help me do what I want?

Comment: Why don't you update memory after updating the database?

Comment: I have to interleave updating memory and the database, and memory updates could fail. Basically, I think what I need to do is test to see if the memory update would fail and batch it up if it won't, then make the fail-proof memory updates after the transaction has been committed. I don't like that since it makes the code harder to read, but *c'est la vie*.